# linear algebra- linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

3. Consider the linear transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by

$$T\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix}\right)
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2x + 3y\\
x-y\\
             x    
\end{bmatrix} $$

(a) Find the standard matrix for T .

(b) Determine whether or not the linear transformation T is (i) onto and whether or not T is (ii) one-to-one. Justify your answers.

Comment: Have you tried anything? This looks like a straight copy-paste.

Comment: Look up on the forum, there are ton of these kind of problems

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
T\left(\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right)=
\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
T\left(\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)=
\begin{bmatrix}3\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$

What's the matrix? What's its rank? Can you apply the rank-nullity theorem?